# Laravel, select last word in tag

Tags: php, laravel

I work with Laravel and in need to select the last word (product code) from the li tag (MRL247MC). The item code is always behind the "|". Problem is that sometimes there are also some words after the h3 tag (Grün in this case).

```
<li>
New Balance baut auf ihre Sammlung von klassischen Silhouetten in diesem Monat. Sie präsentieren den 247 als Teil. Die gepolsterte REVLITE-Zwischensohle wurde beibehalten und das Paar ist mit dem Branding auf der Zunge und einem Satz abgerundeter Schnürsenkel gefertigt | MRL247MC

<h3>Farbe</h3>
Grün
<span class="product-code">Product Code: 271355_sizede</span>

</li>
```

What i have done so far:

```
return $crawler->filter('#itemInfo .menu .expand .acitem li')->first()->text();
```

Maybe you can help me out. Thanks

Comment: Why not just wrap the product code in a span tag with a specific class? that would make it easy to find without having to do some sort of hack. It seems like you are making it harder than it needs to be.

Comment: Because the the info is not on my site ;-)

Comment: I see, is the product code you are looking for always going to have the same length? If so see my hacked together solution [here](https://codepen.io/codemonkeyco/pen/QvoJdQ)

Comment: No, not always the same length and also different for other brands. But this isn't a problem.

Comment: See this [updated codepen](https://codepen.io/codemonkeyco/pen/QvoJdQ). This will find the first word after the `|` no matter how long or short it is. Is this the right direction? If not please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a newline as a separator (`\n`) or have you a way to get text line by line ?

If you can, juste take the first line, and use the pipe as a separator, take the last element and trim, but you surely hava done this part already :)

Answer (score 0):

Parse the HTML instead of text and use regular expression:

```
$html = $crawler->filter('#itemInfo .menu .expand .acitem li')->first()->html();

return preg_match('/\|\s*(\w+)/', $html, $matches) ? $matches[1] : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$el = $crawler->filter('#itemInfo .menu .expand .acitem li')->first();
$text = $el->nodeValue;

$parts = explode('|', $text)

$productCode = trim(end(explode('|', $text)))
```

Using PHP's DOMDoument something like this should work. I believe the `nodeValue` property on a node returns the node text only, excluding child elements.